Конструкции с союзом "как... так и" могут ли обособляться?
Будет ли ошибкой выделить запятыми "как для меня, так и для моих коллег" в данном предложении?
Я изучаю несколько иностранных языков, и это является как для меня, так и для моих коллег очень нужным делом.

Обособление в данном случае может быть авторским решением:
Я изучаю несколько иностранных языков, и это является, как для меня, так и для моих коллег, очень нужным делом.
Пояснение
Обстоятельственный оборот  с  союзами как... так и  соединяет однородные  члены и по общим правилам  не обособляется, так как входит в состав основного сообщения.
Но это не стоит считать единственным решением на все случаи жизни, так как в частных случаях обстоятельство может не вписаться в структуру предложения или иметь значение попутного пояснения. Поэтому обособление должно быть обоснованным каким либо фактором, к примеру пояснительным характером конструкции, как у Розенталя.
§ 14. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные двойными или парными союзами
1. Если однородные члены предложения соединены двойными 
союзами если не…то, хотя…но или парными союзами 
(сопоставительными, градационными) КАК...ТАК И, не так…как, 
не только…но и, не столько…сколько, насколько…настолько и т. 
п., то запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза: Я 
имею поручение КАК от судьи, ТАК И РАВНО от всех наших 
знакомых примирить вас с приятелем вашим (Г.);
Постановка запятой перед первой частью парного союза связана 
с пояснительным характером всей конструкции: Необходимо 
добиваться сокращения ВСЕХ видов оружия, КАК обычных, ТАК И 
массового поражения (Газ.).

В данном случае возможность обособления связана с позицией оборота между двумя частями именного сказуемого: является
очень нужным делом.
Такое расположение  оборота — это авторский выбор, при котором оборот  может приобрести характер дополнительного сообщения.
Сравнить (при изменении позиции оборота):
Обособление однозначно некорректно: Я изучаю несколько иностранных языков, и это является очень нужным делом как для меня, так и для моих коллег.

Курсивом Вы дали предложение с верно расставлеными знаками.
Теперь посмотрим, что станет с предложением при обособлении:
Я изучаю несколько иностранных языков, и это является - как для меня, так и для моих коллег - очень нужным делом.
Обособив "конструкцию", мы просто её очень сильно интонационно выделили. Но предложение сохранило читабельность, ошибок нет: авторская пунктуация.

